# Drupal 7 view custom templates

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have created 1 views which include the 5 types of content types nodes.

What i want to do is customize the view template.

The first 2 stories display in other format like complete title, summary and image

and last 3 stories only title.

How this possible using views.

Or i have to use `$view=views_get_view_result()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the first 2 stories as a regular View (either a page or a block, whichever you want to use) and create the remaining 3 stories as an attachment to the first view.

In the View, you should be able to create an attachment which you can then attach at the end of the first View.

[image: Add Views attachment]

This way, you can have slightly different configurations for each view but still have them in the same View page or block like:

[image: ONE Block created in Views with an Attachment display]

I've posted a lengthier, illustrated step-by-step on my blog at http://nmc-codes.blogspot.ca/2012/10/views-attachment-in-drupal-7.html

Comment: My real problem is not this. Within the same block i have 5 content which 2 i have to with image and reset without image

Comment: @PHPConnect I've edited my answer above to try and make it more clear because I still think that this is what you're looking for.  Or perhaps I don't understand your questions correctly.

Comment: Hay thanks it's working fine. i didn't understand this before.